# django permission groups

Tags: python, django, permissions

I'm creating a my own custom `User` model by extending the `User` model provided by the framework. I also created several model classes and included permissions as per below:

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (("update_values", "update values"),)
```

When I do syncdb, I'm able to see all the permissions populating as they should. My question is, is there a way to associate these permissions with groups as well while syncdb is happening? Right now all of the examples i'm seeing are only if we do it by code, but some groups I want auto generated. Thanks for the help!

**[EDIT]**

I'm trying to load the initial data by creating a file called `initial_data.json` as per below:

```
[
        {
        "model": "django.contrib.auth.models.Group",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "name": "uni_admin"
        }
    },
        {
        "model": "django.contrib.auth.models.Group",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "name": "uni_poweruser"
        }
    },
        {
        "model": "django.contrib.auth.models.Group",
        "pk": 3,
        "fields": {
            "name": "uni_viewer"
        }
    }
]
```

When I run `python manage.py loaddata app/fixtures/initial_data.json`, I keep getting `DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'`...but isn't that the correct model?

Comment: just read your edit - please make this another question, as it's a distinct problem.

Comment: Ok, I will create a new question.

Comment: Actually, I found the error anyway, model is `auth.Group`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using fixtures or custom SQL (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/), but if you're using South to manage your schema updates a "data migration" is IMHO a much cleaner solution (and if you're not using South yet, you should - it really makes life much more easier).

Comment: Nice, never heard of south (I'm new to Django), but it looks like a great tool.

Comment: @kalvish : yes, South is really great. It's just like a version control system in that it takes a bit extra time at first to learn the tool, it puts a little extra constraints, but once you've tried it you just can't imagine going back...

Answer (score 2):

pyaml version for the same

```
- model: auth.Group
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: Admin Group
```

auth.Group is correct name and main reason of errors.